# Protobuf vs JSON - Objective-C/iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, serialization, protocol-buffers

In Objective-C, making iOS apps, what is the best way to go regarding serialization?
Protobuf or JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protobuf is more time- and space-efficient, JSON is probably more nerve-efficient. As long as there is no reason for the former two (e.g. because the amount of data to be serialized is small and serialization is not time-critical), I would stick to JSON.

This also makes debugging more fun :-)

Comment: In the app I'm working time and space are critical, so I think I will have to stick with Protobuf. Do you know any benchmarks or tests made that I can read?

Comment: Unfortunatly only for [JVM-based implementations](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking). However, while protobuf performs better, the performance difference is surprisingly small. Regarding space, it depends on your kind of data. Probably you might just want to try a direct comparison using, e.g., [protobuf-json](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-json/)

Comment: I agree with this, especially if you consider the transparent gzip-encoding, when you're using supported http-servers. JSON – as many text formats – excellently compresses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Protobuf, but [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is a very good choice on iOS. See [JSON vs. PLIST, the Ultimate Showdown](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/) for a performance comparison. JSONKit is widely used and actively developed which makes it a solid choice.

Comment: Thank for you answer, I will see the JSON vs PLIST link, but I'm really interested in Protobuf vs JSON.

Comment: With respect to that site, note that Apple's JSON framework is public as of iOS 5, vis NSJSONSerialization. Expect third party solutions to drop away.

Comment: @Tommy: Since JSONKit seems to be faster and a lot of apps need to support iOS < 5, I don't think you can expect it to go away soon. I'm using it in an app and I don't see any reason to update to Apple's solution in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @FilipeMota: Just had a look, I suggest you play around using a test app before using Protobuf in your iOS app: you either need to use (Objective-)C++ (can be troublesome) or use the [Objective-C port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-objc/). But it seems to be dead: there was [no release since 2009](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/downloads/list). So unless you know (through testing) that Protobuf is giving you a speed boost over JSONKit *that you need* (Premature Optimization yadda yadda), you might waste time using a solution that's a dead-end or costs too much development time.

Comment: @DarkDust in practice it's going to be 0.03s versus 0.02s sort of differences; you're right that maintenance is going to be the big factor. People are going to keep their third party stuff for as long as they need to maintain iOS 4 compatibility. I think they aren't going to bother with it as soon as they can go purely iOS 5 because of the maintenance costs associated with large third-party frameworks. My experience with iOS 3 frameworks that were outdated by iOS 4 is that these things tend to run for a year or two then slowly suffer digital decay. Contributions just dry up.

Comment: @Tommy: I totally agree with your observation. My feeling is simply that *right now* JSONKit is the best serialization option available provided that you also want to support iOS < 5. Even with iOS 5 it seems to be faster *now* but this could already change with the next iOS version, who knows. If you're only going to support iOS >= 5, then using Apple's implementation is probably the most "solid" solution (as in: this solution will likely be supported for a long time).